# "Yarn: command not found" even after being installed

Tags: bash, npm, installation, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install metronic on my computer and for this I need to have yarn installed. So I ran the command :

> npm install --global yarn 
>   /Users/cbarrial/.npm-global/bin/yarn -> /Users/cbarrial/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
>   /Users/cbarrial/.npm-global/bin/yarnpkg -> /Users/cbarrial/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
>   + yarn@1.16.0
>   updated 1 package in 0.376s

So I guess the installation is working fine but then if I try the yarn command I'm getting this :

> yarn --version
>   -bash: yarn: command not found

I have no idea where the problem could come from, I already have the latest npm and node.js installed and working fine.

Comment: Whatever directory `yarn` was installed into isn't in your `PATH`. `find` yarn then add the containing dir to your `PATH`.

Comment: Add it to your PATH env var like this ->

echo "/Users/cbarrial/.npm-global/bin/yarn" > ~/.bashrc ;
source ~/.bashrc

Comment: The duplicate is a grab-bag of random solutions to similar problems. If none of the answers there work for you, probably [edit] your question to clarify in more detail what you did to install `yarn` and on which platform you are, as well as what you have done to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can install **yarn** in the next way:

```sh
sudo apt-get install curl # Only if you don't have installed curl
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install  yarn
```

This way is an alternative to install yarn on debian/ubuntu, but you can find the alternative installation for different operative systems in the [official page for Yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install) in the section **Alternatives**